# NativeScript : Getting Template parse errors: Only void and foreign elements can be self closed

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I'm creating a sample application in NativeScript. I'm getting template parse errors while running the application in my android device.

My code in template is just :

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd">
  <Page.actionBar>
      <ActionBar title="My ActionBar"/>
  </Page.actionBar>
</Page>
```

I'm getting the following error :

```
Template parse errors:
Only void and foreign elements can be self closed "ActionBar" ("<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd">
  <Page.actionBar>
      [ERROR ->]<ActionBar title="My ActionBar"/>
  </Page.actionBar>
</Page>"): AppComponent@2:6

Error: Template parse errors:
Only void and foreign elements can be self closed "ActionBar" ("<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd">
  <Page.actionBar>
      [ERROR ->]<ActionBar title="My ActionBar"/>
  </Page.actionBar>
</Page>"): AppComponent@2:6
    at DirectiveNormalizer.normalizeLoadedTemplate (/data/data/org.nativescript.neurix/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:13506:21)
    at /data/data/org.nativescript.neurix/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:13499:53
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (/data/data/org.nativescript.neurix/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/zone.js/dist/zone-nativescript.js:190:28)
    at Zone.run (/data/data/org.nativescript.neurix/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/zone.js/dist/zone-nativescript.js:83:43)
    at /data/data/org.nativescript.neurix/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/zone.js/dist/zone-nativescript.js:449:57
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (/data/data/org.nativescript.neurix/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/zone.js/dist/zone-nativescript.js:223:37)
    at Zone.runTask (/data/data/org.nativescript.neurix/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/zone.js/dist/zone-nativescript.js:123:47)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (/data/data/org.nativescript.neurix/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/zone.js/dist/zone-nativescript.js:355:35)
```

When I add the closing tags, another error is showing :

```
Error in app.component.html:0:0 caused by: this.page.frame._getNavBarVisible is not a function

    TypeError: this.page.frame._getNavBarVisible is not a function
        at ActionBar.update (/data/data/org.nativescript.neurix/files/app/tns_modules/ui/action-bar/action-bar.js:146:50)
        at ActionBar.onLoaded (/data/data/org.nativescript.neurix/files/app/tns_modules/ui/action-bar/action-bar.js:140:14)
        at eachChild (/data/data/org.nativescript.neurix/files/app/tns_modules/ui/core/view-common.js:616:23)
        at Page._eachChildView (/data/data/org.nativescript.neurix/files/app/tns_modules/ui/page/page-common.js:266:9)
        at Page.View._loadEachChildView (/data/data/org.nativescript.neurix/files/app/tns_modules/ui/core/view-common.js:619:18)
        at Page.View.onLoaded (/data/data/org.nativescript.neurix/files/app/tns_modules/ui/core/view-common.js:609:14)
        at Page.View.onLoaded (/data/data/org.nativescript.neurix/files/app/tns_modules/ui/core/view.js:82:35)
        at Page.onLoaded (/data/data/org.nativescript.neurix/files/app/tns_modules/ui/page/page-common.js:45:35)
        at Page.View._addViewCore (/data/data/org.nativescript.neurix/files/app/tns_modules/ui/core/view-common.js:962:18)
        at Page.View._addViewCore (/data/data/org.nativescript.neurix/files/app/tns_modules/ui/core/view.js:127:39)
```

Comment: https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular#known-issues

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`<ActionBar title="My ActionBar"></ActionBar>` - you cant use self closing tags.

Comment: It is causing another error : Error in app.component.html:0:0 caused by: this.page.frame._getNavBarVisible is not a function

Comment: im assuming you are using ng2, if that's the case you do not need the <Page>, try removing it and see

Comment: I solved it , that's a bug https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/1517
When I used <StackLayout> instead of <Page>, it disappeared